# Python: Splitting a string into elements and adding them in a list

Tags: python

I've a list with only one element, which in itself is a list of elements.

```
str = '"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET","DOROTHY","LISA","NANCY","KAREN","BETTY","HELEN","SANDRA","DONNA","CAROL"'
```

Now, I want each individual name in that string to included in another list. For that, I understand that I have to split each name individually and then append them with the desired list. Here's the code I wrote for the same:

```
str = '"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET","DOROTHY","LISA","NANCY","KAREN","BETTY","HELEN","SANDRA","DONNA","CAROL"'
li = str.split()
c = li[0]
ip = []
start = c.find('"')
final = c.find('"', start+1)
def iter(start, final):
    e = c[start+1:final]
    ip.append(e)
nstart = c.find('"', final+1)
nfinal = c.find('"', nstart+1)
if(nstart == -1 or nfinal == -1):
    print ip
else:
    iter(nstart, nfinal)
```

However, I don't get anything as output. 'ip' is the list where I intend to store all the names, individually. What seems to be the problem with my code?

Comment: `namelist = nameStr [1:-1].split('","')` ?

Comment: Where did this string come from?  That looks a lot like a row of a CSV file.

Comment: I got that string from a file I'm working with.

Comment: The point is that if it's a CSV file, there's an entire built-in module designed to read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is far more complex than necessary. You could use the comment, or do:

```
foo = '"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET","DOROTHY","LISA","NANCY","KAREN","BETTY","HELEN","SANDRA","DONNA","CAROL"'
output = foo.replace('"','').split(",")
```

Answer (score 2):

First, calling something `str` is bad, as `str` is a builtin function in python.

Second, you can do it with the following:

```
in_list_string = '"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET","DOROTHY","LISA","NANCY","KAREN","BETTY","HELEN","SANDRA","DONNA","CAROL"'
out_list= [element.strip('"') for element in in_list_string.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [the csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for csv data:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> dont_call_me_str='"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA","SUSAN","MARGARET","DOROTHY","LISA","NANCY","KAREN","BETTY","HELEN","SANDRA","DONNA","CAROL"'
>>> list(csv.reader(StringIO(dont_call_me_str)))
[['MARY', 'PATRICIA', 'LINDA', 'BARBARA', 'ELIZABETH', 'JENNIFER', 'MARIA', 'SUSAN', 'MARGARET', 'DOROTHY', 'LISA', 'NANCY', 'KAREN', 'BETTY', 'HELEN', 'SANDRA', 'DONNA', 'CAROL']]
```